# Can't connect to mongodb FROM EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, amazon-ec2, tcp

I have mongodb running on an EC2 instance. After setting `mongod.conf` to accept traffic from `0.0.0.0`, I am able to connect and send queries from my local machine. This machine is set to accept all traffic on port 27017.

I have an express app running mongoose also deployed to EC2 on a different instance. However, I cannot connect to the mongo instance from the express instance. I checked the outbound traffic rules, port 27017 is enabled explicitly, though all outbound traffic is enabled as well.

I can't figure out why I would be able to connect from my local machine but not my EC2 instance. The only thing I can think of is perhaps some setting in the VPC these instances are in. Both instances share the same VPC. Both instances are running ubuntu. The only other difference between my local environment and deployment environment is I'm running node 11 (macOS) locally and node 8 in deployment. Any ideas?

Comment: try `telnet` from another ec2 to check if that port is accessible. also, run `netstat -atnlp`  on mongo server to check if port 27017 is bound to  0.0.0.0

Comment: How does your security group look like?

Comment: @anand indeed, netstat shows mongo listening on `0.0.0.0:27017`

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge On the express server, inbound traffic is allowed everywhere on port 80. All outbound traffic is allowed. On the mongo server, inbound traffic is allowed everywhere on port 27017. All outbound traffic is allowed.